# How can I retrieve my profile with the twitter gem

Tags: ruby, twitter, twitter-gem

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "XX"
  config.consumer_secret     = "XY"
  config.access_token        = "ZZ"
  config.access_token_secret = "ZZZ"
end
```

How can I retrieve my profile information?

Comment: But how do i receive my own twitter id?

Comment: All I have is the consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret

Comment: I got it... The only thing is that twitter was retrieving so few info that I doubt that I was doing right.

Comment: Time zone info + username

Comment: not really because I don't know the username... This is an api all I have is the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following simple steps to use the *Twitter* client gem:

```
# get user id from user name 
id = client.user( 'user_name' ).id

# read user's timeline by id
timeline = client.user_timeline id

# read user's timeline of yours
your_timeline = client.user_timeline
```

you can omit the username, and you get the timeline of current user, so try also to issue:

```
user_info = client.user
```